# Allocating dynamic 2D char array

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, memory-management

gcc 4.6.2 c89

Allocating memory for a 2D array and filling with characters.

However, I don't seem to be filling as when I print nothing is displayed.

Am I doing something wrong here?

```
char **attributes = NULL;

/* TODO: Check for memory being allocated */
attributes = malloc(3 * sizeof(char*));
int i = 0;
int k = 0;

for(i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for(k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
        sdp_attributes[i] = malloc(5 * sizeof(char));
        sdp_attributes[i][k] = k;
    }
}

for(i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for(k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
        printf("attributes[i][k] [ %c ]\n", attributes[i][k]);
    }
}
```

Many thanks for any advice,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two major issues:

**First Issue:**

```
for(i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for(k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
        sdp_attributes[i] = malloc(5 * sizeof(char));
```

You are reallocating `sdp_attributes[i]` at each iteration of the inner loop - thereby overwriting it each time. You probably wanted this instead:

```
for(i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    sdp_attributes[i] = malloc(5 * sizeof(char));
    for(k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
```

**Second Issue:**

```
sdp_attributes[i][k] = k;
```

You are basically writing the lower ascii characters. Most of them are not printable.
Something like this might do what you want:

```
sdp_attributes[i][k] = k + '0';
```

Answer (score 3):

You probably want:

```
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    attributes[i] = malloc(5 * sizeof(char));
    for (k = 0; k < 5; k++)
    {
        attributes[i][k] = k;
    }
}
```

This ignores error checking on the allocation.

It also fixes the name of the array to match the declaration, but your code either wasn't compiling (don't post non-compiling code unless your question is about why it doesn't compile!) or you have another variable called `sdp_attributes` declared somewhere which you weren't showing us.

Your code was leaking a lot of memory.  Each time around the `k`-loop, you allocated a new array of 5 characters and stored the pointer in `attributes[i]` (or `sdp_attributes[i]`), storing the new pointer over what was there before, so you overwrote the value of the first 4 pointers. You could not possibly free the first four items - they were lost irretrievably.  Also, on the last iteration, you initialized the 5th element of the final array, but the previous 4 were not initialized and therefore contained indeterminate garbage.

Also, in your printing loop, the values in the array are control characters ^@, ^A, ^B, ^C and ^D; these do not necessarily print well with `%c` (especially not ^@, which is also known as NUL or `'\0'`).  The `printf()` statement might be better written as:

```
    printf("attributes[%d][%d] [ %d ]\n", i, k, attributes[i][k]);
```

This prints the array indexes (rather than simply the characters `[i][k]` for each entry), and prints the control characters as integers (since the `char` values are promoted to `int` when passed to `printf()`) rather than as control characters.

(It's also more conventional to use `i` and `j` for a pair of nested loops, and `i`, `j`, and `k` for triply nested loops, etc.  However, that's a very minor issue.)

Comment: Yes, I will be using free. My code snippet was just keeping it short.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for(k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
        sdp_attributes[i] = malloc(5 * sizeof(char));
        sdp_attributes[i][k] = k;
    }
}
```

Your erasing the allocated memory every time you loop in the inner most loop. 
Here is a correct version.

```
for(i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    sdp_attributes[i] = malloc(5 * sizeof(char));
    for(k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
        sdp_attributes[i][k] = k;
    }
}
```

And you should fix your declaration:

```
 attributes = malloc(3 * sizeof(char*));
```

to

```
   sdp_attributes = malloc(3 * sizeof(char*));
```

Don't forget to free up all the memory allocated

```
for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
   free(sdp_attributes[i]);
}
free(sdp_attributes);
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to allocate and assign elements to 2d array is as follows (but this is a `int` array, you can try and change it for `char` array):

One thing to note: As mentioned by @Mysticial, you should add/subtract '0' to your `int` value to get the `char` value when using `ASCII` character set (remember our `itoa()` functions!).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
        int row, column;
        int **matrix;
        int i, j, val;

        printf("Enter rows: ");
        scanf("%d", &row);
        printf("Enter columns: ");
        scanf("%d", &column);

        matrix = (int **) malloc (sizeof(int *) * row);
        for (i=0 ; i<row ; i++) 
                matrix[i] = (int *) malloc (sizeof(int) * column);

        val=1;
        for (i=0 ; i<row ; i++) {
                for (j=0 ; j<column; j++) {
                        matrix[i][j] = val++;
                }
        }

        for (i=0 ; i<row ; i++) {
                for (j=0 ; j<column; j++) {
                        printf("%3d  ", matrix[i][j]);
                }
                printf("\n");
        }

        for (i=0 ; i<row ; i++) 
                free(matrix[i]);
        free(matrix);

        return 0;
}
```

Few points to note:

1. error handling should be added for `malloc()`
2. `malloc()`'ed memory must be `free()`'ed